# Why my changes are available in github but not in local repo?

Tags: git, github

I have dev branch on both github and local. I created a new branch(say test), then worked on the bug and committed those changes to the local repo. Then pushed the test branch to git hub.

After QA dev and the test branches were merged on the server. Now I pull the dev branch from git hub to make my local up to date and there were few conflict and I solved it. After this I can see only the old code in my local. But my changes are available on the server. How did this happen and what should I do? Thanks!

Comment: What does `git status` on your local dev branch tell you?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1.
Branches are pushing or pulling not where you expect them to.

Run `git remote show origin` and check if there's some mismatches of branch configured for `git push` and `git pull`.

Option 2.
You may have pulled the dev branch not to the one you are looking at.

Option 3.
Which branch was merged into which? May it be that dev was merged into test (so dev didn't get any new commits)?

Default.
If that doesn't help, please give a link to your GitHub repo (if it is an open one).